# Regarding least squares, value of n in a scatter plot

Tags: algebra-precalculus, least-squares

I am currently in a college algebra class wherein I am required to do a rather lengthy project regarding least squares.

One particular exercise posits the following (keep in mind that in this project we have a set of 20 unique coordinates), 
[image]

I am unclear as to how to calculate this or what the n value is (how do I plug in a value of N is greater than or equal to 2?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit what did you try to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Each of the things under "Show that" can be proven by using the definition of the mean. Note that $\overline x=\frac {x_1+x_2+\dots x_n}n$.  Plug that into your first equation.  There are $n$ of the $\overline x$ so everything adds out.